# Open3 capture of ps -aux crashing screen sessions

Tags: ruby, session

My system is Ubuntu 14, im running several game servers in screens on it, the session where the game servers are running is "alle_server", my screens are "server0", "server1" until "server9"

i have a script that should check if there is a process "server#" while # is the server-number:

```html
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'

while true
        x = Array.new(1)
        x = Open3.capture3('ps -aux |grep "scripts/server." | grep  "[0-9]$" -o')

        for i in 0..10
                if !(x[0].include? i.to_s)
                        p i
                        `screen -S alle_server -X screen -L /home/u220324/cod2/scripts/server#{i}`
                end
        end
        sleep(60)
end
```

Ok, I know its dumb to create that array, still it shouldnt do some weird stuff.... when I run this script in a screen session (even when I don't attach it to the "alle_server" screen, sooner or later ALL screensessions disappear at the same moment), but at this moment all servers from 0 to 9 are online and not down

Is it because i try to start that server10 script which doesn't exist?

ps: I had to use that code snippet because the backticks in the code where messing it up